# How to do web scraping?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get data from other site.

I want these items:

```
apple,anar,andi,arabi,Lucknow ,date
```

…from this site:

```
http://www.upmandiparishad.in/MWRates.asp
```

My original source code…

```
public class readURL {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String generate_URL = "http://www.upmandiparishad.in/MWRates.asp";
        try {
            URL data = new URL(generate_URL);
            URLConnection yc = data.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My updated source code using the [jsoup library](http://www.jsoup.org/)…

```
public class parse3 {

public static void print(String url) throws IOException{

   Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20*1000).get(); 
   Element pending = doc.select("table td:eq(1)").first();

int nex=doc.select("table td:eq(0)").size();

//System.out.println(nex);
System.out.println(pending.text());
//System.out.println(nex);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {


        String url = "http://www.upmandiparishad.in/MWRates.asp";

        new parse3().print(url);

}
}
```

Comment: What did your program output? How is that different from what you wanted it to output? What did you try in order to extract what you wanted from what you got?

Comment: my program giving me an html file where all data is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the page and parse the html for the keywords you are looking for.
For this purpose, since you are using java use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

JSoup can download as well as retrieve the keywords you are looking for.

**UPDATE**
To get the rates of all the items you have to access the select tag.

```
Elements options = document.select("select#comcode > option");

for(Element element : options){
     System.out.println("Price of " + element.text() + ":" + element.attr("value"));
}
```

Comment: Are you able to download the page? where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: i am getting data what i want  but it is coming in same line i want every data in diffrent line

Comment: i updated my jsoup code

Comment: dear can u solve my problem

Comment: does this solve your problem?

Comment: almost  solved  my prob

Comment: I think you should ask a clear separate question for it.